# Kendo mvc grid template format

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

My application is MVC5 C#; using Kendo MVC grid, need to format as currency an item.

```
 columns.Bound(p => p.IsFree).Template(@<text> @if (item.IsFree)
            {
                <span>Free</span>
            }
            else
            {
                <span>@item.Price </span>

            }</text>).Title("Cost");
```

Could not find any documentation how to format @item.Price as currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ClientTemplate** instead of **Template** with if else condition like below

```
columns.Bound(c => c.IsFree).ClientTemplate("# if(IsFree) {#  <span>Free</span> #} else{# <span>#= kendo.toString(Price, 'C') #</span> #}#").Title("Cost")
```

Comment: Thank you Aman, this works well if it is Ajax binding, for server binding I had to use Template.

Answer (score 0):

I used >@item.Price.ToString("c0").

Answer (score 0):

For server-side binding, perhaps you could try:
`.Template(@<text>@if (Model.IsFree) { <span>Free</span> } else { <span>@Model.Price.ToString("C")</span>}</text>)`